# Any risks in creating HGS Guardian?

Tags: hyper-v, tpm

I have a Windows Server 2019 with no physical TPM chip. I want to add a new Windows 11 VM to the several older VMs in Hyper-V on the box. If I run the Powershell scripts such as:

New-HgsGuardian -Name "Guardian11" -GenerateCertificates

and ending with:

Enable-VMTPM -VMNAME "TPM"

from a [Microsoft article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34431.windows-10-enabling-vtpm-virtual-tpm.aspx), is there any danger of the existing VMs or the host getting messed up, or does the HGS only affect any VMs that I explicitly reference?

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, this is a very complex feature to install and get right. Microsoft **strongly** recommend that it is installed in a cluster in case a node is lost. Otherwise, recovery is very difficult, if not impossible.

While it isn't the answer I wanted, I have since found that you can interrupt the Windows 11 installation process and insert some registy keys that will allow you to install it without TPM. Search for 'Windows 11 LabConfig'.

Not recommended for production or critical usage, but allows you to run Windows 11 for testing purposes at least.